# Java not finding main class (that is in the jar)

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have jar built with gradle that errors out whenever I try to run it.

```
$ java -jar com.my.company.app-1.0.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.my.company.App
```

However, when I look at the jar contents the class is clearly there.

```
$ jar tf com.my.company.app-1.0.jar | grep App
com/my/company/App.class
```

Moreover, if I extract the jar contents and run the class directly it works:

```
$ jar xf com.my.company.app-1.0.jar
$ java com.my.company.App
Hey, I'm running
```

The manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.my.company.App
Implementation-Version: 1.0
```

I've tried and looked every usual suspect I can think of and just can't figure out why this thing won't run when it's packaged up in a jar. The class itself looks fine as well:

```
package com.my.company;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
```

The portion of the gradle file to create the jar:

```
task createJar(type: Jar){
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class' : 'com.my.company.App',
            'Implementation-Version' : version
    }
    baseName = project.name
    // grabs all dependencies and adds to Jar
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

I'm stumped here.

Comment: Does `java -cp com.my.company.app-1.0.jar com.my.company.App` work?

Comment: Just checking, is your MANIFEST file in the correct location?

Comment: And the manifest needs a newline at the end too, just in case you missed that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no, it does not.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`). java can also obviously find it since it is able to determine what the main class name is, it just can't find the class afterwards.

Comment: can you remove com.my.company from the Jar name and try.